# How to display "disabled" empty groups into GridView

Tags: gridview, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have just done a simple jumplist, using semanticzoom in windows phone 8.1 universal app.

In zoomed out I use `GridView` to display the alphabet, every letter is a group. I use `CollectionViewSource` to map group and Item.
So I have some empty groups, and I like to show them disabled in `GridView` (zoomed out) but I don't know how to achieve this result by using a style.

This is the result I want to achieve:

[image: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/view/file/70135/1/JumpList.png]

Look at the letter `O` - it is disabled because the group is empty.

Comment: Is there a reason, that you manually implement a `GridView` etc, instead of using the already existing [LongListSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class?

Comment: yes I use windows phone 8.1 universal app

Comment: Shouldn't [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) be the solution to your problem? You got to implement another view for the Win8 part anyway. This will save you time for the WP8 part.

Comment: Windows phone 8.1 Universal App Not have LongListSelector, and I like to use SemanticZoom and gridView :)